# Is Multiattack included in the actions a new lycanthrope gains?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, actions

In the *Monster Manual p.206*, it is written:

> A character who becomes a lycanthrope retains his or her statistics except as specified by lycanthrope type. The character gains the lycanthrope's speeds in nonhumanoid form, damage immunities, traits, and **actions that don't involve equipment**. (emphasis mine)

I guess these actions include things like *Bite*, *Claws* or *Tusks* for the animal/hybrid forms.

But is the *Multiattack* also included in those actions when no equipment is specified ? (this is the case for the wereboar and the wererat)

Example from the wereboar (p. 209):

> **Multiattack (Humanoid or Hybrid Form Only).** The wereboar makes two attacks, only one of which can be with its tusks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes, a PC-lycanthrope can multiattack**. Under any interpretation some of them do, and I argue that all do. (And you can skip to the last paragraph if you don't need to see the argument.)

Like you said, The PC-lycanthrope gains all of the abilities that don't *involve* equipment. A very strict reading would say that any action-paragraph that mentions equipment isn't imported: under this reading the wereboar and wererat import *Multiattack* just fine, but the other lycanthropes all don't import *Multiattack.*

This reading is too strict to make sense. It has the effect of making some afflicted with lycanthropy faster and able to multiattack (*e.g.* wereboar), but some not (*e.g.* werebear). This, even though all *monsters* with lycanthropy can multiattack.

Contrast this with a reading in which each portion of an action-paragraph is evaluated against "involves equipment."<sup>1</sup>
The effect of this reading is that **the PC-lycanthrope gains natural attacks and the *ability* to multiattack, but doesn't gain any *equipment*.**

A few examples, all quotes from the 5e MM pp.208-11:

A **wereboar** gains *Tusks*, doesn't gain *Maul*, and *Multiattack* reads as-is:

> ***Multiattack.*** The wereboar makes two attacks, only one of which can be with its tusks.

A **werebear** gains *Bite*, *Claw*, doesn't gain *Greataxe*, and *Multiattack* can be read like:

> ***Multiattack.*** In bear form, the werebear makes two claw attacks. In humanoid form, it makes two <strike>greataxe</strike> attacks. In hybrid form it can attack like a bear or a humanoid.

A **werewolf** gains *Bite*, *Claws*, doesn't gain *Spear*, and *Multiattack* reads like:

> ***Multiattack (Humanoid or Hybrid form only).*** The werewolf makes two attacks: one with its bite and one with its claws <strike>or spear</strike>.

But even this is a little too much lawyering for me: note that the wereboar or werebear both get to make multiattacks that involve weapons, but the werewolf doesn't. Why? Because we're over-thinking it.

**The action *is* the bold-italic word or few words: the paragraph that follows just explains it.** (See also [AngryGM's article on abbreviating stat-blocks](http://theangrygm.com/abbreviate-stat-blocks/).<sup>2</sup>)
Under this philosophy a PC-wereboar gains *Tusks* and *Multiattack.* A PC-werebear gains *Bite*, *Claw*, and *Multiattack*. And a PC-werewolf gains *Bite*, *Claws*, and *Multiattack*. I then understand that wereboar can attack with tusks *and* a weapon, but not twice with tusks. Werewolves can attack twice--one bite and one that somehow uses the hands--but the PC didn't gain a were-spear when afflicted.

---

<sup>1</sup> - Note that for all of the lycanthropes in the MM, the *only* actions that *do* mention equipment are those relating to their (artificial) weapon attacks.

<sup>2</sup> - Be warned that AngryGM's posts are liberally sprinkled with profanity and/or rude language. Nothing you might not hear on television, but still worth knowing before you innocently head over there.

Comment: Does a level 5 paladin/warrior have 3 attacks then ?

Comment: @Yotus Nope. Multiattack is a separate action from the Attack action, and Extra Attack only grants extra attacks with the Attack action.